# ASP.NET Core 6 and SQL Server view listing - not a CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to develop a simple Razor view of data from a SQL Server database view called *vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE*, using ASP.NET Core 6.

I am not using a `startup.cs` file, as I've read that method is obsolete and we should all be using `Program.cs`. *UPDATE*: ok wrong here. I am new to ASP.net Core.

Here is my code so far in `Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SchedulerCore;
using SchedulerCore.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MovementContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConxStr")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
```

My view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using SchedulerCore.Entities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace SchedulerCore
{
    public partial class MovementContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovementContext()
        {
        }

        public MovementContext(DbContextOptions<MovementContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE> vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.UseCollation("Latin1_General_CI_AI");

            modelBuilder.Entity<vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToView("vwSHIPPINGSCHEDULE", "POTS");

                entity.Property(e => e.LOA).HasColumnType("numeric(18, 4)");

                entity.Property(e => e.beam).HasColumnType("numeric(18, 4)");

                entity.Property(e => e.cargo).HasMaxLength(4000);

                entity.Property(e => e.country).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.details).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.duration).HasColumnType("numeric(8, 2)");

                entity.Property(e => e.end_date).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.flag).HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.sectionID).HasMaxLength(20);

                entity.Property(e => e.shipclass).HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.start_date).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.stevedore).HasMaxLength(20);

                entity.Property(e => e.text).HasMaxLength(100);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My Data Access Model:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using SchedulerCore.Entities;

namespace SchedulerCore.Models
{
    public static class SchedulerInitializerExtension
    {
        public static IHost LoadMovements(this IHost webHost)
        {
            var serviceScopeFactory =
            (IServiceScopeFactory?)webHost.Services.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory));

            using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory!.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<MovementContext>();

                //this is where I am stuck
                //dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                //dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                //SchedulerSeeder.Seed(dbContext);
            }

            return webHost;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to implement a CRUD like most blogs talk about. I just want to generate a List view of the data from my SQL Server database view.

How do I link the sql view to the above model? And what is the OnModelCreating() used for? That I created using scaffolding, in "tricking" .Net Core to generate the code for me from a view.

Thanks for any ideas from here.

Comment: "as I've read that method is obsolete" Where exactly? Just because the .net 6 templates use top level statements, doesn't mean that the old way is actually obsolete.

Comment: You should `EnsureDeleted` / `EnsureCreated` either between `app = builder.Build()` and `app.Run()` (like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime) or in a `BackgroundService`

Comment: Nonsense, the Startup class is still fully supported in .NET 6. .NET 6 adds a Minimal Hosting Model that doesn't require it... though using that model means you lose all of the interesting functionality of the Startup class such as Environment-specific initialization methods (e.g.: ConfigureDevelopmentServices, ConfigureStagingServices, etc.) that go far beyond just tweaking settings in the app.settings file.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks. Now can you answer my question please

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - why please? I am not adding or deleting records in this project.

Comment: So your actual question is just https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - yes that's right, but how can I define this without coding it manually please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Entity Framework db first approach. To get the model of your sql view, you have to scaffold the database.

Here is an example code to scaffold the database using the .NET CLI

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

You should replace the part within quotes with your connection string.

Your view will be modeled as a keyless entity.

The following article mentions how to achieve this in detail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/#reverse-engineering-of-database-views

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. I did this via the Add Scaffolding menu option in VS2022. However it's created a Pages subfolder with the page I want (details). How do I get this displayed?

Comment: You may have scaffolded Identity. That is for different purpose.

You should open powershell in your current project directory and then try the above mentioned code.
If you are using VS 2022, you can also go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console and try the following code : 

Scaffold-DbContext "connection-string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer